# Java Debug Confusion

Tags: java, debugging, runtime

Is a Java program debuggable only when the VM is running in Debug Mode?
Is there any way to change it at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to change it at runtime.

If at all possible, you will have to use a profiler

- [Trace java application at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989008/trace-java-application-at-runtime)

Comment: I found the jinfo is available for changing some flags of VMs. But as you mean it could not be used to turn on something like the Debug mode, am I right?

Comment: ~O~. In my mind, I just consider the profiler as an performance analysis. Thanks I will have a try later. I am interested in what it could show out~

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can suddenly debug if it's not compiled with the -g option.  Your only option is to recompile and redeploy.  But once it's in place you can debug at will.

Comment: the question is about java not gcc

Comment: Does that mean you guys normal use other facilities to find out the system problems like event log except the jdb?

Comment: When a running system meet an issue and the program is not running on debug mode, Should I trace out the problem via the event log?

Comment: In GDB world, I could load the symbols files into the debugger, when I need them. Do you mean the Java could not do it?